# CloudTrail event to trigger Lambda function hosted in different AWS account

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I am working in a scenario in AWS, where I need to trigger a lambda function based on cloud trail even trigger, but the lambda function is hosted in a different account and not in Management account. Is this possible at all?

I know it will work if the lambda is hosted in same account as cloud-trail (Management account of CT).